# Opening and ending tag mismatch error in PHP script

Tags: php

I am developing registration scripts for my website, but I am getting an error:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Opening and
ending tag mismatch: form and label in Entity, line: 132 in (path)
mergeformpost.inc.php on line 21
```

This happens in two different circumstances.

1) When the user enters data that already exists in a primary key field.

2) When the user enters the captcha challenge incorrectly.

This is (what I think) is the relevant code from mergeformpost.inc.php:

```
function MergeFormPost( $page ) {


    set_error_handler( 'myErrorHandler', E_WARNING ) ;
    $dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML( $page->source );  //this is line 21
    restore_error_handler();

    if( $dom === false ) {
        writeErrorLog('Failed to parse HTML form.');
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Seems you are trying to load invalid HTML-markup

Comment: I've actually managed to suppress the error. I know that's bad practice but it doesn't seem to be causing a problem.

Comment: The problem is in whatever is filling in `$page->source`, it's not creating properly balanced HTML.

Comment: `DOMDocument` does a decent job of recovering from those warnings.  Unless you have control over `page->source` and expect it to parse without errors, you can just suppress them if everything else is working.